# Find out running applications in foreground and background

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am working on Mac OS X. How do I find out names of running applications in foreground as well as in background?

Answer (score 5):

You can get all running applications with `NSWorkSpace`

```
NSArray *runningApplications = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

The array contains instances of `NSRunningApplication`

Assuming you mean hidden with background and visible with foreground - the equivalent to the <kbd>⌘H</kbd> shortcut in an application menu – you can filter the array with a predicate

```
NSPredicate *visiblePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden == NO"];
NSPredicate *hiddenPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden == YES"];

NSArray *visibleApplications = [runningApplications filteredArrayUsingPredicate:visiblePredicate];
NSArray *hiddenApplications = [runningApplications filteredArrayUsingPredicate:hiddenPredicate];

NSLog(@"%@", visibleApplications);
NSLog(@"%@", hiddenApplications);
```

To determine which application is currently active, filter with the `active` property.

```
NSPredicate *activePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active == YES"];
NSArray *activeApplications = [runningApplications filteredArrayUsingPredicate:activePredicate];  // actually it's always an array containing one application
NSLog(@"%@", activeApplications[0]);
```

Comment: nicely detailed answer, but can you show how to see which app is the one in the foreground?